# I want to solve the equation

Tags: trigonometry

How to show the equation $4 \sin(x) +3 \cos (x)$ as $r \sin (x-\alpha)$

I tried to solve this using $a \cos(x)+b \sin(x) = c$. But there aren't any to use as $c$

Comment: You want to solve $a \cos(x)+b \sin(x) = r \sin (x-\alpha)$, don't you ? So your $c$ is $r \sin (x-\alpha)$, simply.

Answer (score 3):

Because
$$\left(\frac{4}{5}\right)^2+\left(\frac{3}{5}\right)^2=1,$$
taking $\alpha=\arccos(4/5)$ gives that
$$\cos\alpha=4/5,\quad\sin\alpha=3/5.$$
Hence,
$$4\sin x +3\cos x=5(\cos\alpha\sin x+\sin\alpha\cos x)=5\sin(x+\alpha).$$

Answer (score 1):

The angle-addition formula
$$
\sin(x-\alpha) = \sin(x)\cos(\alpha) - \cos(x)\sin(\alpha)
$$
will help you set up a system of equations for $r$ and $\alpha$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: you should normalize this $$a \cdot sin(x) + b \cdot cos(x) = \sqrt{(a+b)} \cdot \bigg(\frac{a\cdot \sin(x) }{\sqrt{(a+b)}} + \frac{b \cdot \cos(x) }{\sqrt{(a+b)}}\bigg)$$  And than use formula from the post below.

Answer (score 1):

By your method,
Since $$\sin(A+B)=\sin A\cos B +\sin B\cos A$$  Therefore,
$$r\cos\alpha=4$$ and $$r\sin\alpha=3$$ Dividing them 
$$\tan\alpha=\frac{3}{4}$$ or 
$$\alpha=\arctan\frac{3}{4}\approx 37^{\circ}$$
$$\implies \sin\alpha=\frac{3}{5}$$
We get $$r\left(\frac{3}{5}\right)=3$$ 
$$r=5$$
We finally get, $$5\sin\left(x+\arctan\frac{3}{4}\right)$$ $$\approx 5\sin(x+37^{\circ})$$